# Join by column and similar date

Tags: r

I would like to union this data frame but they have particular request.
The `inner join` must be done by column two and by one (date), but the date are not the same. In the first data.frame the date must need before the date in data.frame b.
I have charge also the result that I would like to have, it is possible to do in R?

```
a <- data.frame(one = c( as.Date( "2020-08-24"), as.Date( "2020-08-27" ), as.Date( "2020-08-31" ), as.Date( "2020-09-01" )),
                 two = c("a","b","b","a"))

b <- data.frame(two = c( as.Date( "2020-08-25"), as.Date( "2020-08-30" ), as.Date( "2020-09-05" ), as.Date( "2020-09-11" )),
                 three = c("a","b","a","b"))

result <- data.frame(one = c(as.Date( "2020-08-24"), as.Date( "2020-08-27" ), as.Date( "2020-08-31" ), as.Date( "2020-09-01" )),
two = c("a","b","b","a"), 
three = c(as.Date("2020-08-25"), as.Date( "2020-08-30"), as.Date("2020-09-11"), as.Date("2020-09-05")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
left_join(a, b, by = c("two" = "three")) %>% 
  filter(two.y > one) %>% 
  group_by(one) %>% 
  slice_min(two.y)
```

---

With `dplyr 1.1.0`, you can use `join_by` in `left_join`:

```r
library(dplyr)
left_join(a, b, join_by(closest(one <= two), two == three))
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 4 × 3
# Groups:   one [4]
  one        two   two.y     
  <date>     <chr> <date>    
1 2020-08-24 a     2020-08-25
2 2020-08-27 b     2020-08-30
3 2020-08-31 b     2020-09-11
4 2020-09-01 a     2020-09-05
```